# add to the highlight context menu?

Tags: windows-xp, context-menu

I'd like to be able to select some text, and instead of the normal copy, be able to choose another option of a name I choose, that runs some other program of my choosing.

How do I do that?

Comment: @barlop: This is a vague question, but it appears that you want to add an option in the context menu when you select text where you can run an arbitrary program on the text.  Am I correct?

Comment: @DragonLord you read it right, I don't think it's vague, how else  could it be interpreted? but you added a bit about running the program *on the text* and the bit that you added might be beyond superuser and would need to be more specific. So  the question is just what I asked. Yes it's a general question but so what. It's not too general to answer is it?

Comment: @barlop, sorry and thanks for clarifying.  I won't flag the post.

Comment: @DragonLord  You were thinking of flagging the post?!!!!

Comment: @barlop: LOL - I initially considered doing that, but the post was specific enough for it to not be flagged.  Once again, sorry.  I take flags very seriously, and I only flag a post when something is clearly wrong.

Comment: Did you have a particular program in mind you want to do this with?  The context menu on text selection in Windows is not universal.  Even if you added an option to the Windows common line edit and/or text area controls, that would still leave a lot of programs that use custom controls without it. (like Microsoft Office and Firefox, to name a few)  You probably would be better off using clipboard management software that allows you to run a command based on clipboard content (possibly with a hotkey).

Comment: @Patches  I might end up accepting that, that may well be the best answer. Would you like to post your comment as an answer?